# render with params when setting a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have a link which looks like:

```
= link_to 'Issue?', "issues/new?desc=#{comment.body}"
```

in issues form I pick up the desc params to set my issue description:

```
= form_for(@issue, :url => {:action => 'create',
   :controller => 'issues'}, :method => "post") do |f|
= f.text_field :title,
= f.text_area :description, value: params[:desc]
```

Problem comes when validation of my issue fails. Following line is triggered by issue controller:

```
format.html { render action: 'new' }
```

this renders the user entered title but the issue description doesn't get rendered as I am setting it's value with `params[:desc]`. When `render :new` is triggered `params[:desc]` is nil. How can I set `params[:desc]` in my controller during render?

Routes:

```
get 'issues/new' => 'issues#new'
post 'issues/create' => 'issues#create'
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change `desc` to `description`:

```
= link_to 'Issue?', "issues/new?description=#{comment.body}"
```

Then in your form:

```
= f.text_area :description, value: params[:description]
```

or you can use:

```
redirect_to new_issue_path(description: params[:description])
```

Comment: I tried `locals: {desc: "sdfsadf"}`. it didn't work. I have added more info to my question. My routes changes from `issue/new` to `issue/create` when validation fails. I am not sure it is suppose to be like that.

Comment: Try `locals: {params: params}` as it is. Do not change it.

Comment: i did. Title gets rendered but desc becomes empty. I tried `puts #{params}` in controller and it has `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CQ/xWz68kBy1WWMt2fnmaTKcFP0rqvWQt1KGKY8V8u8=", "issue"=>{"title"=>"sdfsdf", "description"=>"sdfsdsdfsd", "tag_list"=>"", "type"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Report Issue", "controller"=>"issues", "action"=>"create", "user_id"=>"addie", "id"=>"fancy_project"}`

Comment: Okay, I got your problem, since you haven't white listed `desc`, params[:desc] becomes empty.

Comment: well, I realized that too and I changed everything to `description` instead. ie `description=#{comment.body}`, `value: params[:description]` but it has no effect.